# Move cursor ghost when creating a group by selecting multiple existing objects on canvas

Tags: fabricjs, move

fabricjs_2.3.6

I am working on an editor that will allow the user to create textboxes images and rectangles dynamically and that portion of the project works great.  All objects on the canvas will pre-existing before creating groups therefore I do not want to hard-code any fabrics.  I also want to preserve the positional relation between the grouped items.

I am having a problem with creating groups by selecting 2 or more existing objects on the canvas to create a group.  My code works with one exception, if the selected items are not in the upper left corner of the canvas when I create the group the grouped objects remain in the original location as desired but the move handle is in the upper left corner of the canvas.  If you click the move cursor handle ghost and then click a blank area on the canvas the problem goes away and everything works fine after that.

I have had no luck searching for a solution possibly because I'm not sure what controls the move cursor's location on the canvas or if it is actually called the "move cursor".

Here is a picture from my jsfiddle after clicking the group button:
[image]
Here is a jsfiddle link to demonstrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Larry_Robertson/xfrd278a/

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<span> Test 1: select both the line and the text objects with the mouse then click group, works great.</span>
<br/>
<span> Test 2: select both the line and the text objects with the mouse, move the selction to the center of the canvas then click group. This creates the problem where a ghost move handle is left behind in the upper left corner of the canvas.  The move handle did not update to the correct position when the group was created.  If you hover the mouse in the upper left of canvas you will see the move cursor. Click on the move cursor then click any blank part of the canvas then you can reselect the group and it moves properly.  What am I doing wrong???</span>
<br/>
<button id="group">group</button>
<canvas id="c" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', {
  fontSize: 30,
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  left: 0,
  top: 0
});
var line = new fabric.Line([10, 10, 100, 100], {
  stroke: 'green',
  strokeWidth: 2
});
canvas.add(line);
canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();

$('#group').on(("click"), function(el) {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var selectionTop = activeObject.get('top');
  var selectionLeft = activeObject.get('left');
  var selectionHeight = activeObject.get('height');
  var selectionWidth = activeObject.get('width');
  if (activeObject.type === 'activeSelection') {
    var group = new fabric.Group([activeObject], {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });
    canvas.add(group);
    deleteSelectedObjectsFromCanvas();
    canvas.setActiveObject(group);
    group = canvas.getActiveObject();
    group.set('top', selectionTop + (selectionHeight / 2));
    group.set('left', selectionLeft + (selectionWidth / 2));
    group.set('originX', 'center');
    group.set('originY', 'center');
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});


function deleteSelectedObjectsFromCanvas() {
  var selection = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var editModeDected = false;
  if (selection.type === 'activeSelection') {
    selection.forEachObject(function(element) {
      console.log(element);
      if (element.type == 'textbox') {
        if (element.isEditing == true) {
          //alert('At least one textbox is currently being edited.  No objects were deleted');
          editModeDected = true;
        }
      }
    });
    if (editModeDected == true) {
      return false;
    }
    // Its okay to delete all selected objects
    selection.forEachObject(function(element) {
      console.log('removing: ' + element.type);
      //element.set('originX',null);
      //element.set('originY',null);
      canvas.remove(element);
      canvas.discardActiveObject();
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    });
  } else {
    if (selection.isEditing == true && selection.type == 'textbox') {
      //alert('Textbox is currently being edited.  No objects were deleted');
    } else {
      canvas.remove(selection);
      canvas.discardActiveObject();
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    }
  }
}
```

CSS

```
#c {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After making changes on code always do a [setCoords](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords) on the object(s) that got changed.

Here is a one liner you can add after the renderAll to fix your issue:

```
    ...
    group.set('originY', 'center');
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.forEachObject(function(o) {o.setCoords()});
```

Comment: @LarryRobertson Glad I could help... Don't forget to flag it as the correct answer